# h264 and h265 keyint params settings

Tags: h.264, h.265

Fiddling with the h264 and h265 params I found both **keyint** and **min-keyint** settings.

Setting keyint shouldn't force the codec library to use exactly that frame interval?

Do min-keyint have something to do with scene detection and if set it take priority over keyint plain setting ?

TL;DR: I found that h265 default settings are keyint=250 and min-keyint=25 ... what I should expect from that? A fixed length GOP or a variable length one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these two links:

1) [MeGUI/x264 Settings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MeGUI/x264_Settings) for an explanation of the parameters like keyint.

2) [About --keyint --min-keyint and --scenecut](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=165197) for a discussion at Doom9 about how they interact, specifically

> --keyint is the maximum interval. x264 will insert key frames earlier if it deems them beneficial, e.g. due to a scene change. From my
>   experience the majority of key frames are in place because of the
>   properties of the video, not because keyint was reached. The larger
>   --keyint is the smaller the impact on overall key frame placement should be.

Comment: Oh well I see, the name of the setting could have been max-keyint so ;D all would have been more clear this way..

Comment: You can enforce fixed GOP size by setting both to same value.

Comment: Oh yes, nice solution :)